# With open giving file not found error. But isn't with supposed to cover for file not found?

Tags: python, csv, filenotfoundexception

```
def writecsvlog(logdict, file=Path('./log/trainlog.csv'), newline='', encoding='utf-8', logger=None):
    try:
        if not logger is None:
            logger.info('Writing training params in a csv log')
        print('Writing training params in a csv log')
        with open(file, 'a', newline=newline, encoding=encoding) as logfile:
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(logfile, fieldnames=logdict.keys())
            csv_writer.writerow(logdict)
    except:
        if not logger is None:
            logger.exception('Could not write log to csv')
        print('Could not write log to csv')
        raise
```

When I run this function I get the following error.
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log\\trainlog.csv'`
But I thought `with open()` is supposed to create the file if it is not found.

Comment: `with open()` will close the file after the `with` block, even if an exception occured. It will not catch exceptions.

Comment: It does generate the file in `a` mode, but it does not generate the folder `log` for you.

Comment: if You want to catch an error use `try: except` statements